# INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, runtime

Following error appearing while installing app on emulator.

'''Failed to commit install session 27757417 with command package install-commit 27757417. Error: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_MANIFEST_MALFORMED: Failed parse during installPackageLI: /data/app/vmdl27757417.tmp/base.apk (at Binary XML file line #57): com.nfs.mobility.myapp.activities.SplashActivity: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that an explicit value for android:exported be defined when intent filters are present''''

Answer (score 0):

check if you have android:exported="true" and not "false" in AndroidManifest